# Getting error while Connecting to oracle XE with NetBeans IDE

Tags: java, jdbc

I am getting the following error while executing this code

```
import java.sql.*;
public class DatabaseConnectivityTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException
    {

        Connection conn=null;

        try
        {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            System.out.println("Trying to connect to database");
            conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","hr","hr");
            System.out.println("Connected");
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The error that i am getting is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:276)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
        at DatabaseConnectivityTest.main(DatabaseConnectivityTest.java:10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right click on your project folder --> Properties --> Java Build Path --> Libriaries --> Add External Jar --> Your sql connector jar file directory

i hope i was able to help you :)

Comment: It totally worked..!!!!  Thank you... !!!I was trying all sorts of stuff and was pretty much frustrated...m so happy now Thanks again mate..:):)

Answer (score 0):

this is due to you have not included oracle driver in the classpath
If you are using eclipse then try the following

1. right click on your project
2. click buildpath->configure build path
3. click libraries tab
4. click add external jars and give the path of oracledriver jar file

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import java.sql.*;
public class DatabaseConnectivityTest {
public static void main(String args[]){

    Connection conn=null;
    try{
          Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
          System.err.println("The driver is not loaded properly");
    }

    try
    {

        System.out.println("Trying to connect to database");
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","hr","hr");
        System.out.println("Connected");
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
          System.err.println("Error while connecting!");
    }
}
}
```

This code will give you clear idea where your program is failing. If you are getting a message "The driver is not loaded properly then add them to the build path. [Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html) the correct jar file and add them to your project.